# Grandfather Paradox and Can vs Cannot

Tags: metaphysics, time

Varanas and Vihvelin provide responses to David Lewis' 'Can vs Cannot' discussion. Have there been any appropriate counterresponses to these?

Comment: Could you provide references for the discussion and responses?

Answer (score 0):

The most appropriate counterresponse is that physical time-travel is a fiction and the 'Can vs Cannot' hypotheses are exercises in nonsense.

For example, [If you allow faster-than-light (FTL), then you break causality](http://www.physicsmatt.com/blog/2016/8/25/why-ftl-implies-time-travel)